# How to add JAVA_OPTS in yaml file?

Tags: yaml, jboss7.x

How can we add JAVA_OPTS in a YAML document?

We are implementing JBOSS 7.1 with puppet hiera.

When new one is added old one is getting overwritten . For example

```
JAVA_OPTS : '-XX:+UseG1GC'
```

When I add new one as follows:

```
JAVA_OPTS : '-XX+PrintHeapAtGC  -XX+PrintFLSStatistics'
```

Comment: Consider `JAVA_OPTS` as a key, whenever there is multiple values of same key then latest value will be considered

Comment: why not updating the existing key to `JAVA_OPTS: '-XX:+UseG1GC -XX+PrintHeapAtGC -XX+PrintFLSStatistics`

Comment: Tried it but it takes only one parameter .The error displayed is  'expected <block end>'

Comment: wildfly::java_opts: '-XX:+UseG1GC'

Comment: wildfly::java_opts: '-Xloggc:/opt/jboss-eap/gc_logs/jvm-gc.log  -XX:+PrintGCDetails   -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps'                       ....I want to add these in yaml.

Comment: Hope there is not this error in your file: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21144013/2987755

Comment: Also try putting value in double quotes like `java_opts: "-Xloggc:/opt/jboss-eap/gc_logs/jvm-gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps"`, though it does not make any difference.

Comment: Tried with  "...."  yet overwriting the previous one!

Comment: if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
    JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"
-   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "\$-XX:+UseG1GC""
+   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-Xloggc:/opt/jboss-eap/gc_logs/jvm-gc.log  -XX:+PrintGCDetails   -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps""
  The one with - sign is getting removed and new one is getting added now .But I want to add multiple values without removing the previous one...